# how to get to sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

how can echo data by  $sql And $sqll together can anybody solve this issue

```
$sql = "SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid = '13'";
$sqll = "SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid = '15'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$resultt = $conn->query($sqll);
if ($result->num_rows > 0 && $resultt->num_rows > 0){
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() && $roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "NO" . $row["chat_msg"]. $roww["chat_msg"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible by storing data into arrays and then merge them

Comment: Would it be better to make it 1 SQL with `userid in [ '13', '15']` and `order by chat_date desc`, this would output the conversation in 1 loop with the messages in the order they were sent (latest first).

Comment: then how i echo userid 13 and userid 15 in different line

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging the two results, you may be better off just querying all the relevant rows in a single query:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid IN ('13', '15')";
```

Comment: then how i echo userid 13 and userid 15 in different line i want userid 13 in left side and userid 15 in right side

Answer (score 0):

Just put semicolon one after other query so its will return all rows in single query.

like that.

1 option ->

`$sql = "SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid = '13';SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid = '15'";`

2 option -> with in Operater ( The following SQL statement selects all rows that are userid in 13,15) more info check here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

`$sql = 
"SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid IN ('13', '15')"`;

Comment: then how i echo userid 13 and userid 15 in different line i want userid 13 in left side and userid 15 in right side

Answer (score 0):

You have two queries ie-

```
SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid = '13'
SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid = '15'
```

Though this query will work fine, in case it can be optimized as follows -

```
SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND userid IN ('13','15');
```

Instead of two separate queries, you can use only one query for your requirement.

So, the problem that you are facing to print queries will also be solved and query will also get optimized.

Comment: then how i echo userid 13 and userid 15 in different line i want userid 13 in left side and userid 15 in right side

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:-

```
$sql = "SELECT chat_msg, chat_date FROM chat WHERE chat_room_id = '13' AND (userid = '13' OR userid = '15')";
```

Comment: then how i echo userid 13 and userid 15 in different line i want userid 13 in left side and userid 15 in right side

Comment: Use two divs , one in left and one in right . In the left call those with userid 13 and in right call those with userid 15 .